# Start from main activity on application restart

Tags: android

How can I finish all activities and start from main after my application is automatically destroyed and created again? This can happen for example when a user changes a system font. My application class contains the big amount of data which is used by many activities and it gets cleared on app restart, the state becomes invalid, that's why I have to return to the launcher activity and clear all the history.

I tried to call the following code in application's onCreate() method as suggested by Marc [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470870/force-application-to-restart-on-first-activity-android), but it doesn't work:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: howz your activity getting destroyed? what you exactly want ?

Comment: and if you get appropriate answer pls accept one which you find useful..

Answer (score 0):

Just Add Finish() method after starting each activity through your Intent..