# Force application to restart android

Tags: android

I want to restart my app from internal activity and I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564614/how-to-restart-an-android-application-programmatically) that I should this code:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
             .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

The problem is when I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag the app exits and doesn't restart.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Follow the below links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/howto-programatically-restart-android-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, Call to System.exit(0) to close the current activity, solve the problem.

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
             .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
System.exit(0);
```