# Programmatically Restart a React Native App

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Is it possible to programmatically restart a React Native app without writing any native code?

For instance, I know from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564614/how-to-restart-an-android-application-programmatically) that I can restart an Android app with:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
         .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Can I do the same with React Native?

Comment: I'm also wondering the same for iOS

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you want to restart just the JS part, then you can use [React Native Restart Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-restart). This will work on both Android and iOS.

If you want to restart the whole application, There are no react native packages as of now. If you want to create on your own, then check the following link

[Building the custom Android module for React Native](https://medium.com/@sriraman2/building-the-custom-android-module-for-react-native-4317d8e6c31d)

If you find difficulty in writing the base JAVA code, You can generate the boilerplate using [React Native Create Library](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library)

UPDATE:

From 0.62, React Native have added `DevSettings.reload()`. So, if you want to reload programmatically while developing you can use that. Note that this method does not work in production!

[Click here for Doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/devsettings#reload)

Comment: If you are/can consider using Expo you can achieve this with Util.reload(). https://docs.expo.io/versions/v15.0.0/sdk/util.html

Comment: The expo reload method has changed to `Expo.Updates.reload()`

Comment: You don't need this package anymore. `DevSettings.reload()` is native from 62+. Here's the documentation for DevSettings module https://reactnative.dev/docs/devsettings#reload

Comment: The documentation (https://reactnative.dev/docs/devsettings) states that it is 'for customizing settings for developers in development'. Do you use it in  production? I tried it on iOS and the app closes (crashes?) instead of restart.

Comment: `The DevSettings module exposes methods for customizing settings for developers in development.`

Comment: So this means that, this api does not work in production

Comment: Please note that the docs mention `DevSettings` API only works in development.

Answer (score 32):

In addition to what's been said above, you can restart the app using Codepush like so:

```
import CodePush from 'react-native-code-push';
CodePush.restartApp();
```

In fact, that's where [React Native Restart Package](https://github.com/avishayil/react-native-restart#credits) got its code from.

Comment: Restarting like this seems to leak memory though. Do a few restarts and the app will get killed quite fast. Still not sure why.

Comment: @CristianoCoelho That's correct. I've also noticed in my experience that it leaks memory. I'm not familiar with the technical details, but I believe react-native-restart likely also leaks memory because it's extracted from codepush. We see a higher incidence of OutOfMemoryErrors on Android after doing a restart via codepush

Answer (score 16):

For iOS, React Native exposes a "reload" method via "DevSettings" https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/75f2da23c5d557862cf4b7bcdd8a1445b54d1c31/React/Modules/RCTDevSettings.mm#L240-L243

```
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";


NativeModules.DevSettings.reload();
```

Comment: Although this works, it seems to only work on development builds (hence the DevSettings name, I guess). Building to a device through Xcode works, but uploading an archive to the app store / Test Flight crashes on this call. Any way around that (aside from using the react-native-restart package)?

Comment: It seems this works for Android as well, I don't know if it always did or an RN update did it, but I suggest you change your answer - I did not use it at first because I thought it's just for iOS.

Comment: This does not work in release, but works in debug mode. Is there any suggestion for release mode?

Comment: For release mode you can use React Native Restart package (first answer)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ReactInstanceManager` like this

```
final ReactInstanceManager instanceManager = getReactInstanceManager();
instanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground();
```

Comment: how to import `getReactInstanceManager`? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can do as follow:

```
yarn add react-native-restart
react-native link react-native-restart
```

and use as follow:

```
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart'; // Import package from node modules

// Immediately reload the React Native Bundle
RNRestart.Restart();
```

Comment: I tried it with `expo` and I get an error `null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeRestart.default.Restart')`. There is an [issue](https://github.com/avishayil/react-native-restart/issues/100) with auto linking, when without expo. So I guess expo uses auto linking...

Comment: @FotisTsakiris linking is not needed since react native v60

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Expo you can also use https://docs.expo.io/versions/v38.0.0/sdk/updates/ specifically `Updates.reloadAsync()` as an alternative. The `Updates` API from expo allows you to programatically control and respond to over-the-air updates to your app.

Install

`expo install expo-updates`

Use

```
import * as Updates from 'expo-updates';

...

async function reloadApp () {
    await Updates.reloadAsync();
}
```

Comment: this is cause assets not getting loaded for me

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an external package for it.

`DevSettings.reload()` is native from 62+. Here's the documentation for DevSettings module https://reactnative.dev/docs/devsettings#reload

Comment: Is it working in release build? Or just in debug/dev build?

Comment: `The DevSettings module exposes methods for customizing settings for developers in development.`

Comment: @ggDeGreat is there any way to do ion release mode?