# Restart android app after cache clear

Tags: android, background-process

I am using `clearApplicationUserData()` for clear the app cache after install an update of the android application. Once above method runs, app close immediately. Any suggestion to restart the app after close the app itself?

```
if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
    ((ActivityManager)SplashScreenActivity.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .clearApplicationUserData(); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cache cleared", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564614/how-to-restart-an-android-application-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can create a [local broadcast receiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) and a `BroadcastReceiver` that [would listen to it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).
2. Inside `onDestroy` or `onStop` call your `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright looking at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681499/android-how-to-auto-restart-application-after-its-been-force-closed) it seem to have proper get way to do it. Is by adding below code to the startActivity

```
intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(YourApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getIntent()), getIntent().getFlags());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onStop(){

   recreate();

}
```