# Restart the Android application

Tags: android

I've been trying to restart the android application when I switch endpoints. I have 
    `Activity A (MAIN) -> Activity B -> Activity C`. In `Activity C`, I switch my endpoint and call `ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(this);`

This kills the app and launches `Activity A`, but I also see a FATAL NPE in the `onCreate` of `Activity B`. It happens to be coming from classes that I had injected into `Activity B`.

Why is `onCreate` and subsequently `onCreateView` of `Activity B` called?

I do see `Activity A` in the background behind the crash dialog though!

I have tried solutions in [How to 'restart' an android application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564614/how-to-restart-an-android-application-programmatically) and the other links within that link. The result/behavior is the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not really sure why this got downvoted. Is there a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(this)` but if it is trying to rebuild the stack from Activity A -> B -> C, the standard Android lifecycle calls would be made and something NPE'd when it was needed.