# How can I restart application by clicking a button?

Tags: flutter

I want to restart my application by clicking a button.
How can I do like that when click a button?

Comment: What 'restart' do you mean? If you just want to reload entire application, you can recreate your `MaterialApp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flutter, AFAIK it is not available. But you can implement by platform channel.

In Android, You can do this with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564614/how-to-restart-an-android-application-programmatically).

In iOS it is not possible natively also.