# Completely Restart App From Within the Code

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way I can initiate a complete restart of my flutter application from within the code itself?

I mean a restart at the OS level (making an iOS app)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115311/flutter-how-to-force-an-application-restart-in-production-mode, hope youre looking for this

Comment: Thanks, but saw that already... Am looking for a way to restart at the OS level.

Comment: Sorry you can't really restart the app at OS level in iOS.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Actually with 'restart_app' plugin you can.

Comment: @HosseinYousefpour You may use `exit(0)` that will shut the VM process, but the app can be suspended by Apple and it's definitely not safe to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restart the app at OS level as far as iOS is concerned due to Apple ecosystem.

However, you can do that in Android, you'll have to use `MethodChannel` approach, here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564614/how-to-restart-an-android-application-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "restart", you might be able to set an exception handler in your `main`, and at the level you want to "restart", throw that exception, catch it in main, and re-run your `RunApp`.