# Completely reboot app android

Tags: java, android, reboot

I would like to know how do you make an app restart COMPLETELY
clicking on a preference. Can you give me some code snippet? I would
like that clicking on a preference with written Reboot it restart the
application completely

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: Simply because i need of the possibility to restart my application

Comment: Try this. (use search in future)
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470870/force-application-to-restart-on-first-activity-android/3772987#3772987][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470870/force-application-to-restart-on-first-activity-android/3772987#3772987

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```