# How to re-open top activity when root activity is in singleTask mode

Tags: android, android-activity, android-navigation, android-task

There are activities A and B. Activity A is app's entry point.

I don't want to have multiple tasks with my app in the system, so I launch activity A in singleTask mode.

A starts B (B is started in standard mode).

When user presses Home button from activity B, and then starts the application again from home screen by clicking app icon, he gets to activity A. But I want him to land in activity B.

What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25635546/7822962) answer. I believe you could save the state of Activity A and parse it when it is launched again, forwarding the pipe to Activity B

Comment: But why do I have to pipe? Why system does not open the top activity of the task (that is B) automatically for task rooted from singleTask activity?