# Activity and Flags Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, flags

I want to launch an Activity with an Intent instance like this :

```
intentListAlarmActivityWakeUpActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

this Activity finnish when i click on a button, but when i see in the overview screen (list of recent activities), i have not the task of my application.
I want only exclude my activity, not the entiere task of my application.

I want to see this:

[image: what i want to see]

But i see that (the full task of my app disappears, not only the activity):

[image: what i see]

I don't understand the flag: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS ?

it is only for the activity launched by the Intent instance, not the full task of my application, but the flag exclude the full task from the overview screen

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry i saw this post but i don't understand the solution, i need to add android:taskaffinity to my <activity> in the manifest, but why ?

Comment: You can also search what affinity is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872989/android-task-affinity-explanation

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks a lot, it works and i understand now (Android dev. documentation speaks about)