# restart/refresh whole app on click of a button

Tags: android, android-intent

My main activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyGame(this));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

where whole content is with in Mygame class,and I want whole app to restart on click of button which is in MyGame class, how can I do so, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470870/force-application-to-restart-on-first-activity) and tried it but nothing worked

```
OnClickListener retryClicklistener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//          Intent i = getContext().getPackageManager()
//                   .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getContext().getPackageName() );
//                   
//                   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
//              //   startActivity( MyGameLongClick);
//          Intent startActivity = new Intent();
//          startActivity.setClass(this,OTHER_ACTIVITY.class);
//          startActivity(startActivity); 


        }};
```

Comment: I thought of using OnRestart(){onCreate()}bt not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be `recreate()`  can help you out..

Comment: how can I use it from MyGame Class

Comment: is your MyGame Class extends Activity??

Comment: get the reference of activity by passing throw methods and call activity.recreate()

Comment: MainActivity myActivity = (MainActivity) getContext();
    myActivity.recreate();

Answer (score 2):

If that's the main activity, you can use the following method to restart the application:

```
private void restartSelf() {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 1000, // one second
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, getIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                    | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    finish();
}
```

And call `restartSelf()` from `onClick()`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    restartSelf();
}
```

This will restart your app after one second of button press.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think You can do like this. You cant restart activity not whole application.

because Life-cycle of android app is stack. and activity on activity you can not close all the activity at a time. [Read this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and [this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)