# Exit an android app and avoid it to restart with previous intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

My app has a restore feature which allows to replace the current database and settings with a the one from a backup file.

The app reacts to the backup opening through intent-filters
I have some code to handle the file in an Activity onCreate method

```
if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
String scheme = intent.getScheme();
// valid scheme are files or content in case of mail attachment
    if (scheme.equals("file") || scheme.equals("content")) {
        uri = getIntent().getData();
    } else if (scheme.equals("http") || scheme.equals("https")) {
        uri = getIntent().getData();
        remoteUri = true;
    }

    // reset intent
    setIntent(new Intent());
    processURI(uri, remoteUri);
}
```

Then in my processURI() function I do all the work and I finish with by displaying a popup telling the user the app will now restart.
Then I call system.exit(0);

It works fine but the app is reopened automatically on the same Activity with the original intent even though I reset it before... how can I avoid this ?

Comment: Not an answer, but you should not use system.exit()

Comment: Why is that ? I want to shutdown the app, and there's no other way to do that. What I want is just to get rid of the original intent when the app restarts

Comment: Use finish() on the activity.  Why do you want to "shutdown" the app?  Do you shutdown a website?   It screws up Androids memory management when you exit.

Comment: I meant 'restart' because after having replaced the app current database and settings, I NEED it to be restarted (it has background services). Finishing the activity won't help

Comment: It's a shame you didn't add that information in the question.  Would have saved time.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772987/4428462) for how to restart your app.

From the linked answer:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
     getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Edit: try;

```
 getActivity().finish();
 System.exit(0);
```

Also, calling `recreate()` will restart the current activity.

See [this answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17166729/4428462).

Comment: This doesn't restart the app. It just restart the default activity

Comment: Did it work? To kill your entire app you can also use `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`