# restart android app using the intent flags

Tags: android, android-intent

on event of language change im just want to restart the android app to reflect the ui changes so here is my code:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                  .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
startActivity(i);
```

**which is working fine with android lollypop and jellybeans but its not working with the kitkat**

**Android:launchMode ="singleTask"**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force application to restart on first activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470870/force-application-to-restart-on-first-activity)